# Percentages in a mail merge

Tags: excel, ms-word, percentage, mailmerge, mergefield

I am trying to add in percentages into a mail merge. I have see other posts saying to press ALT F9 to create a mergefield and then add *100#0% and then toggle twice.

I'm not too sure how to toggle twice or if this is the correct way to go about getting a percentage instead of the long 0.9853564646E-2

I have tried researching how to fix this but can't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

**References:**

- Here is [my article on dealing with fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).
- [Formatting Fields with Switches](http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm) by Graham Mayor, Word MVP

It all depends on how the data is in Excel, to some extent.

**Alt+F9** toggles display of field codes. Many computers have hijacked the function keys for proprietary uses and require the addition of the ***Fn*** shift key.

You would want something like:

> [image: Screenshot of field]

*(The screenshot above is from Graham Mayor's page. Search for "Percentage" for more.)*

Remember, when you are done editing your field, press Alt+F9 again to toggle display back to field results.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra column to your spreadsheet that changes the percentages to text. The mail merge will use the text values exactly as they're displayed in Excel. Set the number format to the pattern than suits your needs.

No decimal places: =TEXT(A2,"0%")

[image]

1 decimal place: =TEXT(A2,"0.0%")

[image]